# For "Querying Data in Staged Files" in Snowflake what does the syntax "=>" mean?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the Snowflake Documentation for "Querying Data in Staged Files" why is the syntax for the "Pattern" & "Format" parameters "=>" instead of "=" whereas for the COPY INTO  syntax the "Pattern" & "Format" parameters have "="?

The documentation doesn't mention anything about this difference so I'm confused.

">=" means Greater than or Equal to

"<=" means Less than or Equal to

So, what the hell does "=>" mean?

Link to the documentation for "Querying Data in Staged Files": https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html

Link to the documentation for "COPY INTO ": https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Link to the documentation for Snowflake Query Operators: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general when you define function or stored procedure it will have a specific signature. This signature has to be matched during the routine call.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(a INT, b TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
AS
$$ 
CONCAT(a, ' ', b)
$$;

SHOW FUNCTIONS LIKE 'TEST';
-- TEST(NUMBER, VARCHAR) RETURN VARCHAR
```

When calling test function argument order has to match its signature("positional notation"):

```
SELECT test(1, 'b');
-- 1 b
```

It is possible to use [named parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter) for user defined objects and explicitly state parameters("named notation"):

```
SELECT test(a => 1, b => 'b');  
-- 1 b
SELECT test(b => 'b', a => 1);
-- 1 b
```

---

Some built-ins constructs also allows to use named parameters `=>` (for instance [FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) or [staged file clause](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/from.html#staged-file-clause)).

Using FLATTEN as it is easier to produce self-contained example:

> ```
> FLATTEN( INPUT => <expr> [ , PATH => <constant_expr> ]
>                          [ , OUTER => TRUE | FALSE ]
>                          [ , RECURSIVE => TRUE | FALSE ]
>                          [ , MODE => 'OBJECT' | 'ARRAY' | 'BOTH' ] )
> ```

All 3 invocations are correct:

```
-- no explicit parameters names
SELECT * FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(parse_json('{"a":1, "b":[77,88]}'), 'b')) f;

-- parameters names order: input, path
SELECT * FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(input => parse_json('{"a":1, "b":[77,88]}'), path => 'b')) f;

 -- parameters names order: path, input
SELECT * FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(path => 'b', input => parse_json('{"a":1, "b":[77,88]}'))) f;
```

**EDIT:**

[Calling a UDF](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/udf/udf-calling-sql)

> **Calling a UDF**
>
> In general, you call a UDF same way that you call other functions.
>
> If a UDF has arguments, you can specify those arguments **by name** or **by position**.
>
> When calling the UDF, you can specify the arguments by name:
>
> ```
> SELECT udf_concatenate_strings(
>   first => 'one',
>   second => 'two',
>   third => 'three');
> ```
>
> If you specify the arguments by name, you do not need to specify the arguments in any particular order:
>
> ```
> SELECT udf_concatenate_strings(
>  third => 'three',
>  first => 'one',
>  second => 'two');
> ```
>
> Note the following:
>
> -You must either specify all arguments **by name** or **by position**. You cannot specify some of the arguments by name and other arguments by position.
>
> - When specifying an argument by name, you cannot use double quotes around the argument name.
>
>   If two functions or two procedures have the same name but different argument types, you can use the argument names to specify which function or procedure to execute

Related: [UDFs, UDTFs, and Stored Procedures Support Passing Arguments by Name](https://docs.snowflake.com/release-notes/2023-06#udfs-udtfs-and-stored-procedures-support-passing-arguments-by-name)

Comment: So, basically, "=>" means the same thing as the "=" in some functions when specifying parameter arguments?

Comment: @JTD2021 It is safe to say that `=>` works as an assignment/association operator in this context.

Comment: Btw, how did you figure this out? I'm trying to get better at figuring things like this out by myself too. I checked Snowflake docs. and they never talked about it but when you explained it, it seems so obvious.

Comment: @JTD2021  Named/positional parameters are common concept in general programming. As for `=>` similar is used by [other RDBMSes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-A5DA8CF5-1BCC-4ABE-9B68-DB593FF1D2CC). I agree that it should be explicitly stated in docs.

Comment: @JTD2021 Please see my updated answer; references to docs have been added